# How to achieve the "Keep Variable Values" in Postman collection Run through newman command

Tags: newman, postman-collection-runner

I am trying to achieve the option "Keep Variable Values" in Postman Collection Runner with newman.

The "Tests" section in my script writes to an environment variable and when I loop it through dataset it keeps on appending to the environment variable.

```
var responseData = JSON.parse(responseBody)

var data = {
    "principalid" : responseData.principalid,
    "principalroleid": responseData.principalroleid,
}

var arrayOfJson = []
if(pm.environment.get("usrresponseData") == ""){
    arrayOfJson.push(data)
    console.log(arrayOfJson)
}
else {
    arrayOfJson = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('usrresponseData'))
    arrayOfJson.push(data)
    console.log(arrayOfJson)

}
pm.environment.set('usrresponseData', JSON.stringify(arrayOfJson));
```

[Screenshot of Postman Runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABtXY.png)